# Bests way to copy MySql data to another table every minute on the same server

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert, insert-into, mysql-insert-id

I have a table `tbl_transaction` getting around 3000 entries per minute.
I copy the data to another table `tbl_transaction_history` every minute and delete tbl_transaction entries which are more than 3 months old.

To copy data from tbl_transaction to tbl_transaction_history, I use mysql Query-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_transaction_history select * from tbl_transaction;
```

Is it the best way of doing this?

tbl_transaction have millions of records with primary key as ID. 
So, while running the query will mysql try to insert ignore every row from tbl_transaction to tbl_transaction_history again and again?
OR
Mysql will only pick the rows not copied and only copy them?

basically, I tried to know but cant found that How will this query work every minute? If, this query is not efficient, what should I do to achieve the same.

Comment: You'd have to check the efficiency, but what about a trigger every time a row is inserted?

Comment: I thought of trigger but, With every insert a trigger with another insert will be less efficient than the one I am using now. No?